# Project build failed while using .net class library in .net core console application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have .Net Core 3.1 console application which is referring to a class library project `FxCore` which is added as a reference.
class library csproj has `<TargetFrameworks>net45;net451;net452;net46;net461;net462;net47;net471;net472</TargetFrameworks>` I have tried changing it to `<TargetFrameworks>net45;</TargetFrameworks>`, but still getting the same error.

I am getting the below error., I have tried clean -> ReBuild, Reopen the visual studio 2019 (version 16.5.2)

> 1>------ Build started: Project: FxCore, Configuration: Debug Any CPU
> ------ 1>J:\Test\core\fx-core\FxCore.csproj(3,3): warning MSB4011: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Microsoft.Common.props"
> cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props (40,3)".
> This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import
> will be ignored. 1>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.targets(37,3):
> warning MSB4011: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.CSharp.targets"
> cannot be imported again. It was already imported at
> "J:\Test\core\fx-core\FxCore.csproj (120,3)". This is most likely a
> build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored.
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2081,5):
> warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
> the assembly "FXEntity, Version=1.0.1.12, Culture=neutral,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on
> disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
> compilation errors. 1>FxCore ->
> J:\Test\core\fx-core\bin\Debug\FxCore.dll
> 1>J:\Test\core\fx-core\FxCore.csproj(3,3): warning MSB4011:
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Microsoft.Common.props"
> cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props (40,3)".
> This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import
> will be ignored. 1>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.targets(37,3):
> warning MSB4011: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.CSharp.targets"
> cannot be imported again. It was already imported at
> "J:\Test\core\fx-core\FxCore.csproj (120,3)". This is most likely a
> build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored.
> 1>J:\Test\core\fx-core\FxCore.csproj(3,3): warning MSB4011:
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Microsoft.Common.props"
> cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props (40,3)".
> This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import
> will be ignored. 1>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.targets(37,3):
> warning MSB4011: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.CSharp.targets"
> cannot be imported again. It was already imported at
> "J:\Test\core\fx-core\FxCore.csproj (120,3)". This is most likely a
> build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored.
> 1>J:\Test\core\fx-core\FxCore.csproj : warning NU1603: FxCore depends
> on Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation (>= 1.3.0) but
> Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation 1.3.0 was not found. An
> approximate best match of Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation 1.4.11
> was resolved. 1>Done building project "FxCore.csproj". 1>Done building
> project "FxCore.csproj". 2>------ Build started: Project:
> CoreConsoleApp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
> 2>J:\Test\core\fx-core\FxCore.csproj(3,3): warning MSB4011:
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Microsoft.Common.props"
> cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props (40,3)".
> This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import
> will be ignored. 2>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.targets(37,3):
> warning MSB4011: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.CSharp.targets"
> cannot be imported again. It was already imported at
> "J:\Test\core\fx-core\FxCore.csproj (120,3)". This is most likely a
> build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored.
> 2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1655,5):
> warning NU1702: ProjectReference 'J:\Test\core\fx-core\FxCore.csproj'
> was resolved using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the
> project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This project may
> not be fully compatible with your project.
> 2>J:\Test\core\CoreConsoleApp\Program.cs(2,7,2,9): error CS0246: The
> type or namespace name 'FX' could not be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)
> 2>J:\Test\core\CoreConsoleApp\Program.cs(7,24,7,32): error CS0246: The
> type or namespace name 'FxCommon' could not be found (are you missing
> a using directive or an assembly reference?) 2>Done building project
> "CoreConsoleApp.csproj" -- FAILED.
> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

But in the Program.cs I am able to use the code, IntelliSense not showing any error.

```
using System;
using FX.Core;
namespace CoreConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private static FxCommon _fxCommon = new FxCommon();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            _fxCommon.Logger.LogWrite("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to run the console application due to this, please help.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: how to solve this issue? and make the solution build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Core *doesn't consume* .NET Framework (`net###`) targets; it can consume `netstandard*` and `netcoreapp*`.

So; your `FxCore` is going to need to target/multi-target one of .NET Standard or .NET Core.

In terms of choice of *what* to target/multi-target:

1. target `netstandard*` - if you don't need anything framework-specific in the implementation
2. multi-target `netcoreapp*` and `netstandard*` - if you want to use `netcoreapp*` features when they are available, or use a down-level common implementation otherwise
3. multi-target `netcoreapp*` and `net###` - if the implementations are completely platform specific and no common implementation is possible

(where `*` / `###` is your choice of versions - probably `netstandard2.1`, `netcoreapp3.1` and `net472`/`net48` at the current time)

Comment: I have solved the issue by removing a few lines from csproj file,I have mentioned that in my answer. please let me know if its wrong wat.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by removing the below lines from the class library csproj file.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net45;net451;net452;net46;net461;net462;net47;net471;net472</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: that's odd; you are *required* to specify a target framework or frameworks, otherwise you get a `NETSDK1013` build error - is there another `<TargetFramework>` / `<TargetFrameworks>` element coming from somewhere else in the tree?

Comment: @MarcGravell in csproj file there is another line `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>`

Comment: There's no need to add *all* possible frameworks though. Why was this added in the first place? Was there another bug, and this line was added to silence it?

Comment: It was already there, I just cloned the project today @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: nope, checking locally, adding `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>` does nothing useful to prevent `NETSDK1013`. There's something more involved in your build.

Comment: do you want me to provide the full csproj file? @MarcGravell

Comment: @viveknuna *really no*; I just want to convey that whatever you've cloned is not a trivial / vanilla case; if you've fixed it: great; but this "fix" is specific to your project only

Comment: @MarcGravell I have started getting some weird issue now, I have posted the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62790722/how-to-solve-nuget-targets124-5-error-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-f

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62793231/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-configuration-configurationmanager-vers