# How to solve NuGet.targets(124,5): error : Value cannot be > null. (Parameter 'folderName') error?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package, .net-4.6.1

On building the project I am getting this error.

> Error NETSDK1004  Assets file
> 'J:\Test\core\fx-core\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet
> package restore to generate this file.    FxCore  C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets 234

So to solve this I am running the command `dotnet restore` in package manager console. But on running I'm getting the below error.

> PM> dotnet restore J:\Test\core\fx-core\FxCore.csproj(3,3): warning
> MSB4011: "C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Current\Microsoft.Common.props" cannot be
> imported again. It was already imported at "C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props (40,3)".
> This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import
> will be ignored.  C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.targets(37,3):
> warning MSB4011: "C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" cannot be imported
> again. It was already imported at "J:\Test\core\fx-core\FxCore.csproj
> (118,3)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent
> import will be ignored.  C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\NuGet.targets(124,5): error : Value cannot be
> null. (Parameter 'folderName') [J:\Test\core\fx-core\FxCore.sln] PM>

How to solve this issue?

.Net Target framework: 4.6.1

Visual Studio: 2019 (16.5.2)

Project Type : Class library

**Update:**

Adding csproj file based on @Lennart request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{459BF9F7-69C7-4BBD-B566-CEFB992F88D5}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>FX.Core</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>FxCore</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Version>1.0.2.9</Version>
    <Company>INTL FCStone</Company>
    <Authors>INTL FCStone</Authors>
    <Description>FxCore Assembly</Description>
    <Copyright>Copyright 2018</Copyright>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>version 1.0.2</PackageReleaseNotes>
    <TargetFrameworkIdentifier>.NETFramework</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="packages\**" />
    <Compile Remove="_CreateNewNuGetPackage\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="packages\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="_CreateNewNuGetPackage\**" />
    <None Remove="packages\**" />
    <None Remove="_CreateNewNuGetPackage\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Dapper, Version=1.50.2.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>packages\Dapper.1.50.2\lib\net45\Dapper.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EasyNetQ, Version=0.63.6.463, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>packages\EasyNetQ.0.63.6.463\lib\net45\EasyNetQ.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="FXEntity, Version=1.0.1.12, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>packages\FXEntity.1.0.2.12\lib\net45\FXEntity.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>packages\log4net.2.0.8\lib\net45-full\log4net.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>packages\CommonServiceLocator.1.3\lib\portable-net4+sl5+netcore45+wpa81+wp8\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>packages\Unity.4.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>packages\Unity.4.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.RegistrationByConvention, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>packages\Unity.4.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.RegistrationByConvention.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ninject, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>packages\Ninject.3.2.2.0\lib\net45-full\Ninject.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RabbitMQ.Client, Version=3.6.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89e7d7c5feba84ce, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>packages\RabbitMQ.Client.3.6.6\lib\net45\RabbitMQ.Client.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties\" />
    <Compile Remove="Configuration\UspHostLoginValidateResult.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Configuration\UspHostUserRoleMenuListResult.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Folder Include="DataAccess\" />
    <Folder Include="DataAccess\Components" />
    <Folder Include="Diagnostics\" />
    <Folder Include="Diagnostics\Components" />
    <Folder Include="NetworkProtocols\" />
    <Folder Include="Unity\" />   
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="app.config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Connect.SSO" Version="3.5.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" Version="5.2.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="1.50.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="EasyNetQ" Version="0.63.6.463" />
    <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation" Version="1.3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Ninject" Version="3.2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RabbitMQ.Client" Version="3.6.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!--<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;" />
  </Target>-->
</Project>
```

Comment: ultimately, this is something to do with whoever setup up the build files for this project/projects... in many non-standard cases, there is a "build" file somewhere that does the things, or some notes on building it

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you for your comment. how can I go ahead and fix it? please explain a bit

Comment: that's like saying "there's a problem in my code; how do I fix it?" - we can't answer that without doing a lot of looking; if I recall, you cloned this from somewhere - I'd start by looking there: is there a "how to build" file? is there a CI build you can look at? can you ask the authors?

Comment: I am building using visual studio in 2019. I cannot see any CI build, I cannot ask the author. I have just. Correct me if I misunderstood your question @MarcGravell

Comment: here's the thing: a normal/standard build will *just work* - `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build`, and you're done; so whatever this is: *it isn't a normal/standard build*; they could be doing *literally anything* in there. Getting to the bottom of it may be hard, and frankly it might be easier to throw away the csproj (just the csproj, not the actual code) and put a new one together from scratch. But there is no pithy "here's how you do that" answer to this, because it *depends on a lot of details*

Comment: oh, and any .targets, .props, etc files could all be contributing the oddness

Comment: Can you post the csproj of the project in question? I've seen this error with duplicate MSBuild imports. Also delete the bin and obj folders of the project and restart VS.

Comment: Can it be related to the .net framework installed on my machine? @MarcGravell

Comment: @Lennart I tried deleting the obj folder and restart VS already. Please give me 2 mins, I will update the question

Comment: @Lennart I have added the csproj files in the question, please check

Comment: @MarcGravell I have added the csproj file to the question, please let me know if something I can fix in it

Comment: I'd start by removing the two `<Import>` elements, but... that project is a bit of a mess

Comment: @MarcGravell so what is the easiest way to solve this

Comment: once again: I'd start by removing the two <Import> elements, but without actually having the project and code in front of my, I can't test it

Comment: @MarcGravell I deleted both the `Import` and then run `dotnet restore`. Warnings are gone now PM> dotnet restore
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\NuGet.targets(124,5): error : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'folderName') [J:\Test\core\fx-core\FxCore.sln]
PM>

Comment: @MarcGravell shall I upload project on Github for you?

Comment: @viveknuna if it isn't private code, sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217447/discussion-between-vivek-nuna-and-marc-gravell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the csproj, a few things leap out:

- there's two `<Import>` that look unnecessary - remove/comment them
- there's no target framework(s) - try `<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>` or similar in the first `<PropertyGroup>`
- the root element is overly complex; can be just `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`
- you don't need `<Reference>` elements for things that also have `<PackageReference>` - you can probably remove the `<Reference>` for things like "Dapper" and "Ninject"

  - it would be *preferable* to use package-references exclusively, if possible

but: with those changes, it should work. My guess is that this was a pre-SDK project file that has been manually hacked and tweaked into something close to a working SDK project file.

---

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{459BF9F7-69C7-4BBD-B566-CEFB992F88D5}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>FX.Core</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>FxCore</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Version>1.0.2.9</Version>
    <Company>INTL FCStone</Company>
    <Authors>INTL FCStone</Authors>
    <Description>FxCore Assembly</Description>
    <Copyright>Copyright 2018</Copyright>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>version 1.0.2</PackageReleaseNotes>
    <TargetFrameworkIdentifier>.NETFramework</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="packages\**" />
    <Compile Remove="_CreateNewNuGetPackage\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="packages\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="_CreateNewNuGetPackage\**" />
    <None Remove="packages\**" />
    <None Remove="_CreateNewNuGetPackage\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="FXEntity, Version=1.0.1.12, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>packages\FXEntity.1.0.2.12\lib\net45\FXEntity.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>packages\Unity.4.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>packages\Unity.4.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.RegistrationByConvention, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>packages\Unity.4.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.RegistrationByConvention.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties\" />
    <Compile Remove="Configuration\UspHostLoginValidateResult.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Configuration\UspHostUserRoleMenuListResult.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Folder Include="DataAccess\" />
    <Folder Include="DataAccess\Components" />
    <Folder Include="Diagnostics\" />
    <Folder Include="Diagnostics\Components" />
    <Folder Include="NetworkProtocols\" />
    <Folder Include="Unity\" />   
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="app.config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup> 
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Connect.SSO" Version="3.5.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" Version="5.2.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="1.50.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="EasyNetQ" Version="0.63.6.463" />
    <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation" Version="1.3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Ninject" Version="3.2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RabbitMQ.Client" Version="3.6.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I would not have solved this issue without your help. so now I am able to run the project successfully. but getting the exception . Though I have added System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager just now to the project

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: @viveknuna so add `<PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.7.0" />` ? (in the `<ItemGroup>` at the bottom)

Comment: In which project? I added in class library, but still getting the same exception

Comment: @viveknuna then try both :)

Comment: I have asked this question here also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62793231/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-configuration-configurationmanager-vers?noredirect=1#comment111043513_62793231 users are saying that its not compatible

Comment: @viveknuna .net core consuming netfx? I agree with them entirely - you already asked this earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62789638/23354

Comment: I added in both projects, its working. please add this as answer on the above link

Comment: But again, it will be a question, that why do we need to add the reference in both applications